# Using uniform authentication for API and Web

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, api, authentication, backbone.js

tech stack

- Ruby on Rails
- RESTful JSON API
- Backbone + Handlebar templates + Underscore + JQuery
- OAuth2

I am working on a webapp where I would like all the communication between the browser and controller via JSON RESTful API. I would also like to use the same API for different client apps like mobile and desktop apps.

I am considering the OAuth authentication mechanism for API. This fits in perfectly with Desktop and Mobile app. However if I would use the OAuth for front end too; then that basically means that an end user would be issued an access_token and that would be used to make subsequent requests.

Is there a clean way to handle session timeouts ONLY in webapp while using the same oauth token strategy for Authentication without having to wrap it with a separate persistent session?

Are there any good practices or frameworks that allows us to expose API for client as well as webapp consumption while catering to the specific nuances of each?

I know Foursquare currently uses the OAuth API for both clients and web; but curious as to how they handle authentication with that?

Any help with ideas and implementation would be much appreciated.